# Head First C Safe Cracker - error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant

Tags: c

I have the following code which is directly from Head First C Chapter 5, and I get an error using Clang 7 and GCC 6:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    const char* description;
    float value;
} swag;

typedef struct {
    swag* swag;
    const char* sequence;
} combination;

typedef struct {
    combination numbers;
    const char* make;
} safe;

swag gold = {
    "GOLD!",
    1000000.0
};

combination numbers = {
    &gold,
    "6502"
};

safe s = {
    numbers,
    "RAMACON250"
};

int main()
{
    printf("Contents = %s\n", s.numbers.swag->description);
}
```

Here's the error:

```
> clang-7 -pthread -lm -o main main.c
main.c:29:5: error: initializer element is not a compile-time
      constant
    numbers,
    ^~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I've found many similar Stack Overflow questions but none of them seem to be quite the same code scenario. Here's a REPL of the code:

https://repl.it/repls/TechnologicalCarelessPatterns

Comment: They got `gold` correct. They should have done the same thing with `numbers`.

Comment: It is somewhat implementation-specific what is considered compile time constant and what is not.

Comment: @user3386109 The got `&gold` correct, not `gold`.. Which is strange enough as it is link-time constant...

Comment: @EugeneSh. I was referring to the variable called `gold`, and its usage throughout the program. The variable called `numbers` should follow the same usage pattern.

Comment: You can work around this with `safe s = { { &gold, "6502" }, "RAMACON250" };`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, is there no way to pass the `numbers` struct?

Comment: No; there's no way to use a copy of the `numbers` structure because that is no longer a compile time constant.  Its address is a compile time constant; its value is not, and the initializer that's being complained about is trying to make a copy of the value of the structure.  Adding `const` somewhere won't help; the expression isn't a constant within the terms of the C standard.  C++ has different rules; it is a different language, of course.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are initializing the structures is not proper. That syntax is used to initialize array in C.
Here is the modified version of your code with proper structure initialization.

```
#include <stdio.h>


typedef struct {
    const char* description;
    float value;
} swag;

typedef struct {
    swag* swag;
    const char* sequence;
} combination;

typedef struct {
    combination numbers;
    const char* make;
} safe;

swag gold;
combination numbers;
safe s;

int main()
{
  gold.description = "GOLD!";
  gold.value = 10000.0;
  numbers.swag = &gold;
  numbers.sequence = "6502";
  s.numbers = numbers;
  s.make = "RAMACON250";
    printf("Contents = %s\n", s.numbers.swag->description);
}
```

This is working but this is not a good method for assignment of pointer variables. You need to use strcpy for `char *` and `malloc` for general structure pointers.